# Any way to delete unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: blockchain.info, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

Recently I sent some bitcoins without adding a fee and now, it's been taking too long. Is there any way I can recover my bitcoins? I want to delete my unconfirmed transactions from Blockchain.info?

I am using Blockchain's Wallet.