# Multibit HD shows confirmed transactions as unconfirmed

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit-hd

My entire balance in MultiBit HD appears as "unconfirmed". MultiBit HD does not allow me to send them to another address, so they are "stuck". When I click on the individual transactions under "Payments", the pop-up window says "Unknown transaction status". These transactions are more than a year old, and they seem to exist and be completely valid on blockchain.info (see for example [this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/51b97e25c26e2c7e2a931e347cd67e68d06373daf061a7c13ff5aabd5726a033).

I have already tried the "Repair wallet" option, but it has no effect. I have also tried using accelerators as described in [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54182/multibit-hd-0-5-1-with-unconfirmed-transactions-for-months-now) but also without effect. Likewise [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) question is not helpful since it is about the generel speed of confirmations - my problem is related to MultiBit HD where my balance is unconfirmed even though the transations are confirmed on blockchain.info.

How can I get my bitcoins back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Not the same: that question is about "speeding up" the confirmation. My question is more related to MultiBit HD, where the transactions remain unconfirmed, whereas they appear confirmed on blockchain.info.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to and rename it to something like "Multibit shows confirmed transactions as unconfirmed".  This forum gets a *lot* of "Help!  My transaction is unconfirmed" questions, and questions with titles like yours are almost immediately marked as duplicates.  Making it stick out as a different problem will attract more and better answers.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am stuck with same problem and any advise will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Multibit HD is end of life software so you should migrate to Electrum. The MultibitHD developers themselves advised users to do that. [Here's](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/) a detailed guide.